# using after defined variable in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to access $addlin->tiitle variable to add post title as html title.
unable to do that because i have defined it after the calling.
what i want to do is getting the last post title and want to put in title.
Thanks for any help

```
 <?php
use Carbon\Carbon;
?>
@extends('layout.main')
@section('title',Config::get('settings.title').$addlin->title) // Here i'm trying to get title of post.

@section('body')
@if(Session::has('global'))
    <h3>{{Session::get('global')}}</h3>
@else
@endif
<div class="row top-slider" id="postswrapper">
<div class="container">
<?php
$post1 = array_chunk($listpost, 3);

//dd($post1[1]);
foreach ($post1 as $post_chk) 
{
?>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 part-1">
                <div class="row">
<?php

foreach ($post_chk as $addlin) 
{

        $postid = $addlin->id;
        $tit = $addlin->title; // Here it is defined.
        $url = $addlin->url;
        $credits = $addlin->credits;
        $des = $addlin->description;
        $headline = $addlin->headline;
        $thumbnail = $addlin->thumbnail;
        $out = strlen($tit) > 50 ? substr($tit,0,50)."..." : $tit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the title into a variable before you use it.  Also if you are retrieving the title in a loop then you need to store it in a variable that exists outside of the loop.  Can you have more than one title or only one?  I will assume you can only have one, so we will index it directly using 0.  Put this at the top:

```
$title = $post_chk[0]->title;
```

Then in your template code (I'm assuming that's what Carbon is) you need the php tags in order to access the php variable, like so:

```
@section('title',Config::get('settings.title').<?=$title?>)
```